# Transform matrix to array assigning specific columns

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, transform

I have a numerical matrix of size 17 (rows) x 6 (columns). It looks looks like this:

[image: Numerical Matrix]

Now I want to transform this matrix to an array of size 2 (rows) x 3 (columns) x (17 dimensions) in a way that every row is transformed to one dimension in the new array, in a way that columns 1-3 go to the first row and columns 4-6 go to the second row.

I have used the numbers out of the example to give an example how dimension 1 looks in this new array (it includes the values of the first row):

[image: First dimension of new array]

How can I transform this matrix to the array I would like to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(c(1:12), ncol = 6)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7    9   11
#[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12

a <- array(t(m), dim = c(3, 2, length(m)/6))
a <- aperm(a, c(2, 1, 3)) #switch first and second dimension
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]    7    9   11
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    4    6
#[2,]    8   10   12
```